# Dynamic html table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

How to do dynamic html table on JS **with** jQuery? For example I must have 6 buttons:

- Add row to begin table;
- Add row to middle;
- Add row to end;
- Delete first row;
- Delete middle row;
- Delete last row;

**UPD:**

That's my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#addFirstPosition').click(function(){
            var $tr = $('<tr><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>');
            //var $myTable = $('#myTable');
            //$myTable.append($tr);
            $("#myTable > tbody").append($tr);
        );
        });
```

And this is my html:

```
<input id="addFirstPosition" type="button" value="AddFirst" />
<input id="addMiddlePosition" type="button" value="AddMiddle" />
<input id="addLastPosition" type="button" value="AddLast" />
<br />
<input id="deleteFirstPosition" type="button" value="DelFirst" />
<input id="deleteMiddlePosition" type="button" value="DelMiddle" />
<input id="deleteLastPosition" type="button" value="DelLast" />
<br />
<br />
<table id="myTable" border="1px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click to button, nothing happens.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Hav u tried somethin? U need to post ur code to get help from here.

Comment: I didn't post code, because maybe my code have global fault, and I doing wrong way. That's why I posted this without code, because maybe someone show more best way. But ok, I understand this rule. I'll update topic.

Comment: as a generate note, if a button is **not in a form** you should be using the `button` tag instead of input. with your limited code it cannot be seen whether this is all in a form or not. `<button type='button' id='someId'>value</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were errors in your js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addFirstPosition').click(function() {
        var $tr = $('<tr><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>');;
        $("#myTable > tbody").append($tr);
    });// I WAS MISSING A } BEFORE );
});​
```

brackets missing or in the wrong places. The code above is corrected and I commented on the mistake.

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/J6kwP/)

but [Parv Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650041/829835) had some good points in his/her answer.

Answer (score 6):

going by the format in which u have asked this ques
search for the rows by doing a $(tr);
then use

```
.append(); for adding to the last
.prepend(); for adding to the first
select an elemnt by doint $(tr).eq(index).after() to add in between
```

after you have selected the row
which you can do by

```
var r = $(tr).eq(index)
```

to delete you can do

```
r.remove()
```

no matter where you row is present